# Add a webview as HeaderView in a ListView. But the image is not being displayed in webview

Tags: android, webview

I added a headerview in a ListView, and it has a WebView.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    `enter code here`android:layout_width="match_parent"
    *emphasized text*android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
    </LinearLayout>


View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.view_webview, null);
webView = (WebView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.wv_show);
listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
webView.loadUrl("http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzIwNzA0MDYwMQ==&mid=503270115&idx=1&sn=74cf175e5261d7e586b7290122b7277f#rd");
```

The question is, how to display the image in WebView?

Answer (score 0):

try to move this line `webView.loadUrl("http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzIwNzA0MDYwMQ==&mid=503270115&‌​idx=1&sn=74cf175e5261d7e586b7290122b7277f#rd");` befor this                    `listview.addHeaderView(headerView);`